# Java servlet will not compile - cannot find javax.servlet

Tags: java, servlets, classpath

Im having big problems compiling java servlets. As far as i can see, ive done everything i need to do, ive installed tomcat 7 correctly, and tomcat is working. As i understand, i need to add servlet.jar package to my classpath. There doesnt seem to be a servlet.jar on my system but from what i can understand from the tomcat docs, its now servlet-api.jar.

Ive done this, by editing the classpath at `/etc/environment`:

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
CLASSPATH="/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar"

Unfortunately, still no luck, i cant compile java servlets, and im still get warnings about missing symbols for `javax.servlets`.

Im using ubuntu 11.10 x64. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

> *Ive done this, by editing the classpath at `/etc/environment`:*
>
> *`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games" CLASSPATH="/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar"`*

That looks fine. The `PATH` is irrelevant to the particular problem though. It's not been used by Java in any way. It's only used by the operating system platform to look for executabeles. The `CLASSPATH` is similar, but only used by Java to look for classes which are to be used during compile and/or runtime.

Your problem is most likely caused because you used `-cp` or `-classpath` argument of `javac` command. In that case, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable will be **ignored** (this also applies to `java` command by the way, also when `-jar` argument is used).

You need to specify the classpath by **only** *either* the `CLASSPATH` environment variable *or* the `-cp` or `-classpath` argument. The general recommendation is to forget about the `CLASSPATH` environment variable at all as that's considered a poor practice whenever you want to do a bit more than just "Hello World". You can specify multiple paths in the `-cp` or `-classpath` argument using `:`.

```
$ cd /path/to/package/root/of/your/servlet/code
$ javac -cp .:/path/to/servlet-api.jar com/example/YourServlet.java
```

If you get tired of repeating typing this everytime, just put it in a `.sh` script, or use a build tool such as Ant which allows configuration by a XML file, or just use an IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ which will do it all automagically when you just save the source file.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have a CLASSPATH environment variable.

A better way to do it is to use the `-classpath` argument to `javac.exe` when you compile and `java.exe` when you run.  Add the Tomcat servlet-api.jar that way.

Another suggestion is to learn Ant.  It's an XML-driven, Java-based build tool.  It's easier to learn and use than Maven.  I'd start with that.

Answer (score 2):

`javax.servlets` is defined in `servlet-api.jar` so your issue must be with your config somehow.  What are you using to compile?  Are you issuing `javac` commands directly or using a build tool like maven, or ant, or event eclipse?  I would recommend maven because it handles dependencies for you with a single configuration file.  Really easy to pick up too.

In maven, you would need to start by getting maven installed/configured, and start your project with a set file structure (this is simplified but sufficient):

```
/src/main/java - The root of your java files
/src/main/webapp - The root of your webapp
/pom.xml - Maven configuration file
```

So a complete file list for a servlet might be:

```
/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/MyServlet.java
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
/src/main/webapp/index.jsp
/pom.xml
```

The first 3 lines (other than the root file structure) are the same as the would be for any web app, the last is your config file which would look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The important part here is that the dependency on servlet-api is handled by maven, so there is no need to download it, or set up classpaths or anything.  Once you have set this file structure, and edited your pom, you just navigate a console to the root and type `mvn package`.  That will download your dependencies, compile your code, and package your war.  There is a LOT more that maven offers with very minimal modifications.  In contrast, ant would require this:

*to be added*

Comment: "Maven" and "easy" don't belong in the same sentence.

Comment: @duffymo, I've used em both, extensively.  I find maven to be much simpler.  Convention over configuration.  Once you get the very simple convention, you get a whole lot for free.  Most importantly, the dependency management which is particularly handy in this situation (which ant can do if you include ivy which is not very easy to understand).

Comment: I haven't mastered the convention.  Perhaps there's still hope for it, but I find Ant to be far easier.  I'm a Spring user, so most of my dependencies are easily available to me.  Maven gives me more headaches than it cures.

Comment: @duffymo It's easy when it's simple use-cases, like vanilla apps, default repos, no reporting, etc. Past that, yeah, it turns in to a real pain sometimes.

Comment: @duffymo, Im totally a spring guy, but spring does dependency injection (runtime stuff), maven does dependency management (ensures all the jars needed for compile/test/runtime are available in the classpath).  For fun, i will try to add a couple quick examples here...

Comment: I know the difference between Spring and Maven.  My point is that when I download Spring, I get all its dependent JARs at the correct version.  What do I need Maven for?

Comment: @duffymo, Ah, I see.  Its been so long since I actually _downloaded_ anything, so I guess thats what I would say you need maven for.  No need to download.  And changing versions is as easy as changing a number in the pom (at which point it would update all of its dependencies as well).  Also, it would ensure that other packages that had dependencies did not conflict with the dependencies that spring brought in.  Maven dependency management (or even Ivy if you wanna go there) have been real life savers in my experience.

Comment: I can download once and I'm all set.  It seems easier for me to download a version of Spring rather than endure Maven with every operation.

Comment: @duffymo Not everything comes with its own dependencies, nor is it always obvious which *specific* dependencies are *actually* required. IMO it's better to let something else handle transitive dependency management in most cases.

Comment: But Spring comes with 99% of the dependencies I need.  It sorts me out  rather well.  It's like its own Maven repository.

Comment: @duffymo, that would also imply it comes with a lot of things you _don't_ need/want (unless you use everything in every project).

Comment: I may want them sometime, and they do no harm sitting on my hard drive.  I cherry pick what I want and leave the rest behind.  Still easier than Maven.