# javax.servlet package not found

Tags: java

I m new to programing field. I want to learn "java servlet programing". I'm using following Environments

1. Windows 7 OS
2. java SE jdk 7u17
3. apache-tomcat-7.0.37

I set up the tomcat server as per the instruction given in the official website.
And started the server. Im trying to run the simple servlet Hello_word program which is in the book "java Servlet Programming 2nd Edition " By O'Reilly.

As instruction given in the book, I saved the file in the name of Hello_word.java and tried to compile it using javac command in Windows CMD prompt.It gives an error  Javax.servlet.... package not found. Used notepad to code the program.

I   tried to solve as given in this link  "[Java servlet will not compile - cannot find javax.servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107632/java-servlet-will-not-compile-cannot-find-javax-servlet)"..
still same problem can anyone help me regarding this.... please..... please

Comment: You did not try very hard. The link you posted says exactly how to solve it.

Comment: One note the Apache Tomcat 3.2 used in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `servlet-api.jar` file to your classpath.  It should be included with Tomcat.